# Semantic Issue - sizeof not supported in this platform

Tags: ios, objective-c, sizeof

I am having an issue with a xcode project. As I am new on this platform, I nered some help to solve this problem.

XCode Error:

> ../Classes/CDeck.m:66:37: Application of 'sizeof' to interface 'CCard'
>   is not supported on this architecture and platform

Code:

```
-(void) CopyFrom:(CDeck *)Deck
{
    Nbr=Deck.Nbr;
    memcpy(Cards,[Deck GetByID:0], Nbr*sizeof(CCard)); // Here is the error
}
```

If you need any information about the project just tell me.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Using `sizeof` and `memcpy` on Objective-C structures like that seems like a  _REALLY BAD_ idea. The compiler might not even let you do that by default, hence the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because this is not a stack allocated type.  Use `sizeof(CCard *)` to get the size of the pointer (regardless of the heap memory).